# Рамка не отображается вокруг элемента

Tags: css3, css

Рамка не отображается вокруг элемента, а только по углам, а в Хроме всё отображается корректно. Вот код:

```
#borderimage {
    -moz-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
    -o-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
    -webkit-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
    border: 30px solid #40c4c8;
    border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
    border-width: thick;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @drumgog, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

```
border: 30px solid #40c4c8;
```

Переместите этот стиль в начало. Поясню: `border-image` хром, видимо, понимает, остальные (где вы смотрели) нет. У вас стиль

```
border: 30px solid #40c4c8;
```

Перетирает стили выше:

```
-moz-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
-o-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
-webkit-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
```

и получается, что отрабатывает только следующий.

То есть:

```
#borderimage {
  border: 30px solid #40c4c8;
  border-width: thick;
  -moz-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
  -o-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
  -webkit-border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
  border-image: url("border-image.png") 30 round round;
  padding: 20px;
}
```